# How to use asset/source imported by js files imported in entry.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, three.js, bundler, loader

In my entry.js file, I import a lot of js files like so:

```
import {airplane} from "./path/to/airplane.js"
```

In `airplane.js`, which uses ThreeJS, there are some file imports such as:

```
OBJLoader().load("./path/to/object.obj");
```

My webpack config file is arranged like so:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./path/to/entry.js",

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.*.obj$/i,
                type: "asset/source"
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
};
```

**Is it possible for Webpack to load the content of `object.obj` using asset/source or asset/resource?**

For context, I am doing this to bundle everything into one `bundle.js` file so no file paths are needed. Additionally, I don't always know the path to `object.obj`, so a wildcard filepath would be nice. Thanks in advance!